# Delete tab-delimited columns matching sub-string in first line

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I would like to delete all tab-delimited columns from a text file in which the header (first line) contains the string "_HET". The input text file looks like this:

```
rs36810213_HET   rs2438689   rs70927523570_HET   rs54666437   ...
1                0           2                   0
0                1           0                   1
2                0           1                   1
...              ...         ...                 ...
```

The output text file should look like this:

```
rs2438689   rs54666437   ...
0           0
1           1
0           1
...         ...
```

The code I am using does not remove anything:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/data/folder"

awk -v OFS='\t' '

NR==1{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i=="_HET") {
            n=i-1
            m=NF-(i==NF)
        }
    }

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))
        printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS
}

' $path/input.txt >> $path/output.txt
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F '\t' -f script.awk file
```

where `script.awk` is

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }

FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i !~ /_HET/)
            keep[i] = 1
}

{
    nf = split($0, fields, FS)
    $0 = ""
    j = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        if (i in keep)
            $(++j) = fields[i]

    print
}
```

This first parses the headers on the first line and remembers which ones we're interested in keeping in the `keep` associative array.

Then, for each line, it re-creates the current record (the line) from only the fields that we're wanting to keep, and prints it.

It does this by (re-)splitting the line on the current field separator into the array `fields`, then empty *all* fields (with `$0 = ""`; this resets `NF`), and finally assigning only the fields from `fields` that are keys in the `keep` array.

Some people like one-liners:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i!~/_HET/)k[i]=1}{n=split($0,f,FS);$0=j="";for(i=1;i<=n;++i)if(i in k)$(++j)=f[i]}1' file
```

---

I didn't quite follow your code completely, but `$i=="_HET"` will compare the `i`:th field to the string `_HET`.  This test will fail unless the value of the field is *exactly* `_HET` (which none of your header field are).

---

A totally different approach:

```
cut -f "$( awk -F '\t' -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i!~/_HET/)k[i]=1;$0="";for(i in k)$(++j)=i;print;exit}' file )" file
```

This uses the `awk` program

```
BEGIN { OFS = "," }

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i !~ /_HET/)
            keep[i] = 1

    $0 = ""

    for (i in keep)
        $(++j) = i

    print
    exit
}
```

not to output the *contents* of the wanted columns, but to output their column numbers as a comma-delimited string.  This string is then used by `cut` to cut out the columns from the data.

Comment: Thank you. The output is space-delimited. How can I have it tab-delimited?

Comment: @mitch I fixed this in a recent revision to the question already.  `OFS` must be set to the same thing as `FS`, and you set `FS` to a tab using `-F '\t'` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Perl as shown:

```
$ perl -F'/\t/' -pale '$"="\t";
    $. == 1 and @A = grep { $F[$_] !~ /_HET/ } 0 .. $#F;
    $_ = "@F[@A]";
' input.tsv
```