# awk: extract tab-delimited columns matching sub-strings in first line

Tags: awk

I would like to extract tab-delimited columns from a text file ("columns.txt") in which the header (first line) matches certain strings listed in another text file ("strings.txt").

"columns.txt" looks like this:

```
rs2438689   rs54666437   rs9877702046   rs025436779...
0           0            0              1
1           1            2              2 
0           1            2              0 
...         ...          ...            ...
```

"strings.txt" looks like this:

```
rs2438689
rs9877702046   
...
```

The output text file "output.txt" should look like this (tab-delimited):

```
rs2438689   rs9877702046...
0           0              
1           2               
0           2               
...         ...
```

Any suggestions on how to do this with awk? Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have a script that matches a single string (e.g. "rs2438689") and removes all columns containing it: `awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i!~/rs2438689/)k[i]=1}{n=split($0,f,FS);$0=j="";for(i=1;i<=n;++i)if(i in k)$(++j)=f[i]}1'` Problem 1: How to read in multiple strings from another text file? How to keep columns matching the string and delete the rest? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying [my solution for your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521322/116858):

```
awk -F '\t' -f script.awk strings.txt columns.txt
```

where `script.awk` is

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }

FNR == NR {
    columns[$1] = 1
    next
}

FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i in columns)
            keep[i] = 1
}

{
    nf = split($0, fields, FS)
    $0 = ""
    j = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        if (i in keep)
            $(++j) = fields[i]

    print
}
```

Here, the `FNR == NR` block would only execute while reading from the first file listed on the command line (`strings.txt`).  It would populate the `columns` array with keys that are the names of the columns.  The rest of the code is *more or less* unchanged from the old solution, apart form where we check whether the current column is one that we'd like to keep (in the `FNR == 1` block).

---

Addressing the [questions in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521337/awk-extract-tab-delimited-columns-matching-sub-strings-in-first-line/521347?noredirect=1#comment963778_521347):

To always copy the first six columns and to cut the column headers at `_`, change

```
FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i in columns)
            keep[i] = 1
}
```

into

```
FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sub("_.*", "", $i)
        if (i <= 6 || $i in columns)
            keep[i] = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What would be the solution if the headers in "columns.txt" would look like this                `rs2438689_G   rs54666437_A   rs9877702046_C   rs025436779_A ...` so that "strings.txt" only matches substrings `rs2438689 rs9877702046 ...`? 2. How can I tell awk to just copy the first 6 columns and do the extraction from column 7 to the final column? Thank you!

Comment: @mitch We usually discourage followup questions in comments. If you have further questions, then either modify the actual question (which may invalidate given answer, so it's not a good idea either) or ask a new question.  I have addressed your followup questions in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Awk, how about making a comma-separated list of column names from `strings.txt`, and using that as a list of `namedcol`s for `csvtool`:

```
$ csvtool -t TAB -u TAB namedcol "$(paste -sd, < strings.txt)" columns.txt
rs2438689   rs9877702046
0   0
1   2
0   2
... ...
```

or similarly with `csvcut/csvformat` from the Python-based `csvkit`:

```
$ csvcut -tc "$(paste -sd, < strings.txt)" columns.txt | csvformat -T
rs2438689   rs9877702046
0   0
1   2
0   2
... ...
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$_}=1 }
                     else{ @i = grep { $h{$F[$_]} == 1 } 0..$#F if !$c++;
                           print join "\t", @F[@i]}' strings.txt columns.txt
rs2438689   rs9877702046
0   0
1   2
0   2
```

- `if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$_}=1 }` for first input file, create a hash with line content as key
- `@i = grep { $h{$F[$_]} == 1 } 0..$#F if !$c++` for first line of second file, create an index list of all matching column names from the hash
- `print join "\t", @F[@i]` print the matching columns

Comment: 1. What would be the solution if the headers in "columns.txt" would look like this `rs2438689_G rs54666437_A rs9877702046_C rs025436779_A ...` so that "strings.txt" only matches substrings `rs2438689 rs9877702046 ...`? 2. How can I tell perl to just copy the first 6 columns and do the extraction from column 7 to the final column? 3. How can I tell perl to print the columns to a new text file "columns_new.txt"? Thank you!

Comment: for the 3rd question, just add `> columns_new.txt` to the command.. that is a shell feature, will work with other commands too.. for the first two, I get the feeling that your nature of work might require more such adjustments.. I'd advice to learn awk/perl from basics, I've a repo https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing dedicated for such tools which might help you

Answer (score 0):

Is the script very complex (i.e. `awk` a necessity) or your data very big? You could use `datamash` to transpose your datafile, `grep` columns (now lines) with the strings file and retranspose:

```
datamash transpose < in.txt  | grep -f strings.txt  | datamash transpose > out.txt
```

Like that you can also get the non-matching columns:

```
datamash transpose < in.txt  | grep -f strings.txt -v  | datamash transpose > out.txt
```

---

EDIT:

Since you are working on a very large file, `cut` might do the deal: the first (headers) line of your data is transformed to one line per header, `grep` selects the line numbers matching `strings.txt` entries and thus we have the field (column) numbers we need for `cut` which are then retransformed to comma-separated values for `cut`'s field selection.

```
cut -f $( grep -n -f strings.txt <( head -1 data.txt | tr '\t' '\n' ) \|
   sed 's/:.*//' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//' ) data.txt
```

Again non-matching columns arise from using `grep -v`.

Comment: awk is needed since I am working on a 22GB file.

Comment: Maybe `cut` can do the deal.

Answer (score 0):

Done by using below script it may be long it worked fine

k=`wc -l file1| awk '{print $1}'`

```
for ((i=1;i<=$k;i++));  do for j in `cat file2`; do awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '$i == j {x=NR+k}(NR<=x){print $i}' file1; done ; done>final.txt

z=`wc -l final.txt| awk '{print $1}'`

for ((i=1;i<=$z;i++)); do j=$(($i+3)); sed -n ''$i','$j'p' final.txt >file_starting_with_$i.txt; i=$j; done

paste file_starting_with*
```

output

```
rs2438689   rs9877702046
0       0
1       2
0       2
```