# Extract columns from text file matching header substrings

Tags: awk

I would like to extract tab-delimited columns from a text file "columns.txt" in which the header (first line) matches substrings listed in another text file "strings".
"columns.txt" looks like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   rs243_A   rs546_G   rs987_T   rs025_C   ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   0         0         0         1         ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   1         1         2         2         ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   0         1         2         0         ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
```

"strings.txt" looks like this:

```
rs243
rs987  
...
```

The output text file should copy columns 1-6 from "columns.txt" and then add all extracted columns (tab-delimited) specified in "strings.txt". The output file "output.txt" should look like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   rs243   rs987   ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   0       0       ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   1       2       ...
A   B   C   D   E   F   0       2       ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ...     ...     ...
```

The code I am using prints columns 1-6 to "output.txt" as I want, but does not add the extracted columns:

```
awk -F '\t' -f /data/p_00614/ABCD/scripts/extract.awk /data/strings.txt /data/columns.txt > /data/output.txt
```

with "extract.awk":

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }

FNR == NR {
    sub("_.*", "", $1)
    columns[$1] = 1
    next
}

FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if (i <= 6 || $i in columns)
            keep[i] = 1
}

{
    nf = split($0, fields, FS)
    $0 = ""
    j = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        if (i in keep)
            $(++j) = fields[i]

    print 
}
```

I think that

```
sub("_.*", "", $1)
```

does not work. `"_.*"` probably does not cut every substring starting from `_` but just exact matches. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Does the array contain what you expect? Try printing it `{ for (i in keep) print keep[i] }`. Also: maybe bundle your questions - they are all on the same problem.

Comment: No it doesn't. It contains columns 1-6, but not the additional columns.

Comment: Your titles/headers don't seem to match strings.txt as they have `_X` in them. Without these letters the script works. Also consider using `cut` as described [before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521337/awk-extract-tab-delimited-columns-matching-sub-strings-in-first-line) and add `cut -f 1,6`.

Comment: But `sub("_.*", "", $1)` should remove all `_X` so that strings should match!?

Comment: OK. `sub("_.*", "", $1)` does not remove `_X` so that strings do not match and nothing is printed to the output. I will ask how to fix the `sub` command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us _actual data_ we can use to test our answers. You talk about columns 1-6 but only show us 4 columns. We need to see an accurate and full example of a few lines of your input data and the output you would expect from that input data. By the way, based on the files you're showing, I think you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the code that I provided in [an earlier answer to one of your questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521347/116858) (now corrected).  The `_.*` bit should not be removed from the strings being read from `strings.txt`, but from the data being read from `columns.txt`.

Corrected script:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }

FNR == NR {
    columns[$1] = 1
    next
}

FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sub("_.*", "", $i)
        if (i <= 6 || $i in columns)
            keep[i] = 1
    }
}

{
    nf = split($0, fields, FS)
    $0 = ""
    j = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        if (i in keep)
            $(++j) = fields[i]

    print 
}
```

Note the very slight changes to the `FNR == NR` and `FNR == 1` blocks from what you have in the question.